# How to share mounted volumes to a different Docker instance?

Tags: mount, sshfs, docker, container

I’m working on a log gathering/analysis solution that uses `sshfs` to mount remote drive for acquiring the updates of the logs in realtime. Now I want to create a Docker user to process the log that makes use of this remote drive from the `sshfs` Docker.

I’ve tried with `volumes-from`, with which only the file system device were mounted but not the mount table so I can’t see the content of `sshfs` from the processor’s container. Here’s what I did:

```
$ docker run --volumes /sshfs --rm -it --name "my_sshfs_1" --privileged my_sshfs
# mkdir /sshfs/logs  # in the container
# sshfs user@ip:remote_dir /sshfs/logs &
# ls /sshfs/logs
log1 log2 log3
```

In another terminal:

```
$ docker run --volumes-from my_sshfs_1 --rm -it ubuntu
# ls /sshfs     # in the container
logs
# ls /sshfs/logs
(empty)
```

I expect the last `ls /sshfs/logs` would show up the same files as the `my_sshfs_1` container does but it doesn't. Is there a way I can achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finished up solving this problem by establishing an additional sshfs between the two dockers. I am still looking for better solutions :)